# Отключить контекстное меню при долгом тапе

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, css3

На сайте есть выпадающее меню на bootstrap 4. На десктопе при наведении выпаадет меню, при клике идет переход на страницу.
на мобилах же при коротком нажатии идет переход, как и нужно, а при долгом нажатии помимо разворачивания меню вылезает контекстное меню - как его отключить?
UPD Делал так:

```
    <script>
    function absorbEvent_(event) {
      var e = event || window.event;
      e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation && e.stopPropagation();
      e.cancelBubble = true;
      e.returnValue = false;
      return false;
    }

    function preventLongPressMenu(node) {
      node.ontouchstart = absorbEvent_;
      node.ontouchmove = absorbEvent_;
      node.ontouchend = absorbEvent_;
      node.ontouchcancel = absorbEvent_;
    }

    function init() {
      preventLongPressMenu(document.getElementById('dropdownKaminy'));
    }
  </script>
<body onload="init()">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light top_menu">
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1" aria-controls="navbar1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="/">Главная</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="[~2~]">Наши работы</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="[~4~]" id="dropdownKaminy" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Камины</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownKaminy">
                                    <li>Пункт 1</li>
                                    <li>Пункт 2</li>
                                    <li>Пункт 3</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav> 
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413683/disabling-the-context-menu-on-long-taps-on-android

Comment: У меня не получилось почему-то

Comment: там есть еще в ответах неплохие предложения

Comment: все там перепробовал - работает только css свойство: pointer-events: none;
Но оно отключает также и переход по ссылке. Как бы сделать так, чтобы и переход работал?